# Unity TileMap Grid not showing in Android

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm using TileMap Grid on My Project. It's work well in edit mode, but not showing in Android apk project.

So, I wonder that, it is normal? or any solution do you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh I got a solution my self! it is camera problem.
move to Camera(render) z pos far to tilemap or change projection to Orthographic
it should work! good luck